# Firefox 44.0.1 opening two tabs , when running selenium webdriver code

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

My Firefox recently got updated recently. My firefox version is 44.0.1. When I run a simple code as below in selenium webdriver, two tabs are opening in firefox. How can i get rid of the unwanted tab. I changed Firefox setting, but still two tabs are opening. one tab is a plain tab and the second tab is https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34612/what-is-the-skype-extension. How can I load my URL that I want to automate in a single firefox window. Do I need to change any firefox setting.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Another {
    @Test
    public void tester(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Firefox Profile and save it with name after making settings as per your requirement. Please call this profile in script.

[Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) is the steps to create firefox profile

Below is the script for example

```
 ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

 FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("CreatedProfile");

 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Is it the issue with new firefox version?